# Can Bran Stark see into the future?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have only watched the tv show, is there any definitive answers on whether Bran can see into the future?

I may of misinterpreted the following two scenes but it seems like he can, but if he can, it is barely touched upon...

Season one

> he has a dream that predicts his father's death.

Season six

> he sees the explosion of the Sept of Baelor before Cersei even sets her plan in motion.

Comment: He can see events of the present and Past at will. for future, he can only see what the old gods vouchsafe to him in dreams. At least thats how things stand in the books. In the show, well they've run fast and loose with Bran's powers and he's all OP so I guess the answer would be yes for the show too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bran is a [greenseer](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Greenseer), which means he can capture glimpses from the future. However, this does not mean he can stare into the future in the same way he can do so to the past.

> Mostly, I live in the past

Comment: +1 An example that he cannot see the future as clearly is when he claims he doesn't know whether dragonfire will kill the Night King because "no-one has tried it before".

Comment: We don't know if this is the case, as he told Jon Snow, he was where he needed to be, Bran may well have for seen Arya killing the night King and knew Jon had to be distracting the dragon. He may have known telling them that Dragon Fire would not kill the night king would change the plans and so doom them to failure.

Comment: +1 (got to know about 'Greenseers' through your answer.) Also, another supporting example that he can only perceive (and not clearly see) future is- Bran Stark experienced a prophetic dream that his father was in the crypts of Winterfell when Eddard Stark was indeed executed in King's Landing.